# Consume xml data via C# Web Service

Tags: c#

I will need to be able to receive this xml data from a Java WebService and I am not really sure what to expose in my WebMethod so I can consume it? It is just a basic order and items. In .Net I would just have passed an order object List.

I should expand a bit further.  It is an Oracle BPEL process that will need to map to this exposed C# WebService.  I would need to expose the OrderNumber, ItemNumber ,etc (as shown in XML).  The issue I am having is that I would have 1 to Many items ,etc so I can't just expose the basic items (string, int).

Probably pretty trivial for most the community here...just not sure how to do it? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

I could do something like (build an order object and it appears to show the xml as I would expect?)

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Orders> GetOrders(List<Orders> ordersList)
{
  List<Orders oList = ordersList;

  return oList;
}
```

XML:

```
<Order>
  <OrderNumber>12345</OrderNumber>
  <OrderDate>01/25/2010</OrderDate>
  <OrderSource>Affiliate123</OrderSource>
  <Items>
     <ItemNumber>123478</ItemNumber>
     <Qty>5</Qty>
     <UOM>EA</UOM>
     <Description>Test Item</Description>
  </Items>
 </Order>
```

Comment: I don't understand. do you talking about C#, Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Are you trying to communicate with a java based based Web Service using C# based Web-Service ???? Web-Method is in your App!! right

Comment: I apologize.  I am trying to consume the posted xml via a C# web service.  The source the xml will be coming from a Java Web Service.  Web Methods are in my C# app correct...I am just not sure what to expose in the web method to consume the xml?

Comment: It is a SOA service exposed through Oracle SOA.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have answered your own question.  The .NET web services framework will map a return type of `List<T>` to a sequence of `T` at the SOAP level, just as if you had used a `T[]` (array of `T`).

When I write up a quick sample service just like yours, this is the XML it returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetOrdersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetOrdersResult>
        <Order>
          <OrderNumber>int</OrderNumber>
          <OrderDate>dateTime</OrderDate>
          <OrderSource>string</OrderSource>
          <Items>
            <Item xsi:nil="true" />
            <Item xsi:nil="true" />
          </Items>
        </Order>
        <Order>
          <OrderNumber>int</OrderNumber>
          <OrderDate>dateTime</OrderDate>
          <OrderSource>string</OrderSource>
          <Items>
            <Item xsi:nil="true" />
            <Item xsi:nil="true" />
          </Items>
        </Order>
      </GetOrdersResult>
    </GetOrdersResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Your BPEL layer should be able to consume that pretty easily.

Comment: Cool.  I was hoping that it would I just wasn't sure what the best solution was to tring to expose the fields for mapping.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to expose a WebMethod, as I am assuming you are not publishing a WebService, instead you are consuming someone else's WebService.

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if I do then in Visual Studio you just have to "Add Webreference" to the WebService URL and it should automatically create the .NET proxy objects, you can then use these objects to consume the methods.

Cheers,
Mithun

http://blog.mithunbose.com

Comment: Basically what it is (my apologies for not completely explaining) is an Oracle BPEL process that will need to map to this exposed service.  So I would need to expose the OrderNumber, ItemNumber etc.  The issue for me is that I could have 1 to Many Items, etc.

Comment: Could you please let me know the signature of the WebMethod that you are consuming. Please also mention little detail on each parameter on that method and the return value. I guess the XML string will be the return value?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you updated your post and have mentioned the webmethod signature.

Comment: Hi Mithun,

Ordernumber would be a string, ItemNumber would be a string (1 to many items), Qty would be an integer, OrderDate would be a date. Is that what you are looking for? I don't think I will drop a return in there...if I do it will be a validation of the data and I would return something like IsValid (0/1)